js-joda ZonedDateTime gives SYSTEM as zoneId for Singapore/Kuala Lumpur
I am using js-joda library on angular project and in a ts file I fetch ZoneId as follows
ZoneId zoneId = ZonedDateTime.now().zone()
but it gives 'SYSTEM' instead of Current zoneId 'Singapore/Kuala Lumpur'
When I select some other location eg. Beijing in the same zone (+8.00) and revert back to 'Singapore/Kuala Lumpur' from windows settings then I start to get correct time zoneId 'Singapore/Kuala Lumpur'
This is really strange, can anyone please help here?
